# mssql insert data into decimal datatype

Tags: php, .net, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update data into the column with data type decimal(18, 18).

It is throwing on error

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

My query is

```
UPDATE tblname SET latitude ='55.27898669242859', longitude = '25.19762644777814' WHERE id = 1
```

when I remove the quotes(') and run i am getting below error

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
```

I have used CAST and CONVERT also it is not working .

can anyone guess the reason??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While defining the table you have made the mistake. Redefine the column as decimal(18,10) means you can store 10 digits after decimal. By defining decimal(18,18), you can store decimal value less than 1 in the table eg. 0.278986692.